# Listbox onmouseover event to change a textblock text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, mouseover

I want to change a textblock text thanks to a mouseover event on a listbox.
The main issue is that I can't find out how to add a mouseover event on a listbox.
I found a way to select a listbox item on a mouseover event, but I don't want it to select.
I did it this way, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511752/mouseover-to-select-item-in-listbox-in-wpf)

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Where is the TextBlock? In the ItemTemplate or somewhere else?

Comment: it is outside of the usercontrol containing the listbox, so I'll try to call the style given by @Tzah Mama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseEnter"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as ListBoxItem).Content = "Your text";
}
```