# How to fix ListView selection change?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView whose children are the grdis that contain  an image, and four buttons. They are all populated dynamically. Here is the code for selection change event for the ListView:

```
 private void Thumbnails_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) //display large png on click of thumbnail and slide notes
        {

            item = Thumbnails.SelectedIndex + 1; //get original index for each element in ListView


            if (LargePic.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                LargePic.Children.RemoveAt(LargePic.Children.Count - 1); //clear first item in StackPanel
            }


            LargePic.Children.Add(image_array[item - 1]); //show large png of selected ppt as first item in StackPanel



            SlideNotes.Text = slide_notes[item - 1]; //show slide notes in a box below large preview
            //GetNotes(PowerPoint_App, presentation)[item - 1];

            finalize_import.IsEnabled = true; //enable button for next screen

            //selection
            all_hide_buttons[item - 1].Click += Hide_Buton_Click;
            all_show_buttons[item - 1].Click += Show_Buton_Click;
            hide_fade_in_animations[item - 1].Click += Hide_Fade_In_Animations_Click;
            show_fade_in_animations[item - 1].Click += Show_Fade_In_Animations_Click;



        }
```

So as you can see, buttons can be clicked only if specific child (item) is selected on the list and further perform some action based on this item number. My problem is that the SelectionChanged gets executed only if I click on the image which is the part of the child grid in the list, so only then these buttons become clickable. I want it to execute if I click directly on the button, so the button actually clicks immediately if I click it, without the need to click the image first. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding, whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem. Not exactly what I wanted, but it does the job,

[Mouseover to select item in listbox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511752/mouseover-to-select-item-in-listbox-in-wpf)

So, then main thing in my problem was that I need to click listview item first in order to be able to click the button within the item. In the link that I have included you can see that if we add proper event to the listivew, then as we hover an item, selection changed gets triggered automatically, same as if we clicked it, which saves one click and gets the desired button enabled as soon as the mouse is over the item. It is a little bit of cheating, but the main thing here is that the mouse pointer ca not make to this button within listview item before actually touching a pixel from the item.